# I want the old good star back!

Tags: feature-request, design

Can I haz the circle around the star back? Without circle, it looks tiny and not MSE-ish. Want it back.

Old design:

[image]

New design:

[image]

Comment: I ... hadn't noticed that it changed at all until you pointed it out. Dangit man, now I have to have a think on whether I like it or not.

Comment: +1 I liked the old star more a lot. Even if it doesn't come back I want a userscript for the old style of the button.

Comment: @Tim *you don't like it and want the old one you don't like it and want the old one you don't like it and want the old one you don't like it and want the old one*

Comment: I always felt like the circle on the old one added too much emphasis to the star that wasn't needed. I like this one better.

Comment: I don't know, maybe it could use more 'pop' and some lens flare so it twinkles when you hover over it. Because I can see some meta users at their desks all dis-shuffled screaming at their monitors ... ***twinkle.. twinkle .. you goddamn useless star!*** And people say we don't understand our audience well pshhhhh.

Comment: This is what we've come to? Complaining about a star? It's becoming a poll question a this point: (1) Patrick's answer, "I agree, give us the old design"... (2) Shadow's answer: "I like the new design"... perhaps I should add another answer for the poll: (3) "Who Cares? Oh, and happy Monday!"

Comment: @Lynn Wut? You're on Meta. It is place for polls and whining, see the [help] center for moar info.

Comment: Honestly, I'm getting tired of all this bickering about a few pixels of difference (and I'm pretty sure the rest of MSE is too, considering the vote count).

Comment: @Doorknob Eh, sometimes it's pointless in the grand scheme of things, but occasionally something like this prods a larger idea to move, so I don't mind them for the most part. Besides, it's a nice break from yelling at each other about other things :)

Comment: @nicael Yeah :) I was just trying to be funny. It failed :-/

Comment: @Tim meta-meta request: plz remove excess "center" from [my comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250479/i-want-the-old-good-star-back#comment817635_250479).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I really didn't think that many people would notice. There are two reasons the circle around the star was removed:

1. Some of our sites have no circle around the star, and we're looking to normalize variables across network sites in order to be able to release new global features more easily in the future (like the new profile.)
2. It was a logical decision — the thinking was that adding something to your favorites is a less important of an action than upvoting or downvoting. By removing the circle, the star gets less visual weight than the arrows, giving the voting icons more prominence.

Comment: I noticed the overall change, taken from SO/MSO - unless it's not the exact same design?

Comment: _I really didn't think that many people would notice_ People always notice when you move their cheese.

Comment: @bluefeet I was trying to be ironical, but of course that doesn't come through in a post. And yes Shadow Wizard, it's not the exact same design as SO/MSO, but it's very close.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder what poor Jin thinks about it though, wiping away big parts of the design he worked so hard on when splitting the metas... :P

Answer (score 9):

Personally, I like the new star because it seems to be a bit cleaner, but I can see from a UX perspective why it may not be as useful as the old button.

So, for those of you who hate change (or the lack of circles), [here's a userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6196/old-meta-se-stars) that adds the circles back.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Old Meta.SE Stars
// @namespace      http://greasyfork.org/
// @include        *://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @exclude        *://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged
// @author         Cameron Bernhardt (AstroCB)
// @version        1.0
// @description    Reverts to the old Meta.SE star style
// ==/UserScript==
var newStyle = document.createElement("style");
newStyle.innerText = ".envelope-on, .envelope-off, .vote-up-off, .vote-up-on, .vote-down-off, .vote-down-on, .star-on, .star-off, .comment-up-off, .comment-up-on, .comment-flag, .edited-yes, .feed-icon, .vote-accepted-off, .vote-accepted-on, .vote-accepted-bounty, .badge-earned-check, .delete-tag, .grippie, .expander-arrow-hide, .expander-arrow-show, .expander-arrow-small-hide, .expander-arrow-small-show, .anonymous-gravatar, .badge1, .badge2, .badge3, .gp-share, .fb-share, .twitter-share, #notify-container span.notify-close, .migrated.to, .migrated.from { background-image: url('https://web.archive.org/web/20150221090806/http://meta.stackexchange.com/content/stackexchangemeta/img/sprites.png?v=145e63c0320f'); } .star-on, .star-off { height: 50px; } .votecell .vote-count-post { margin: 5px 0 17px 0;  }";

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newStyle);
```

Answer (score 8):

I like the old one better from a 'user experience' point-of-view. The design itself doesn't matter a lot to me.

The old button is in line with the upvote and downvote buttons. Novice users will sooner see this is something to click, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 8):

I'm going to agree that taking away that circle seems to make the feature a little less easy to discover. Then again, I'm not certain the star does the best job of advertising the feature *with* the circle either. From a design perspective I think I could go either way, so advertising the feature better is probably the best criteria.

Not declining or accepting, because I think we're going in circles here. Is the star (adorned with a glorious circle or not) *really* the best way to advertise this? The whole 'favorite' thing is a little strange to begin with because it's useful to apply to posts that you simply want to *watch* but don't necessarily have 'love' for (thus, a heart is out of the question).

While this has come up, *multiple* times in the past, I'm open to links to feature requests you were fond of that suggested an alternate icon. Not saying there are any plans of changing it, but another look at the feature itself is on my plate for this year so ..

I'm thinking more .. *Watch and waypoint this post*, which is essentially why people that know the button works click it in the first place, at least most of them.

Comment: "I think we're going in circles here" - ha, ha. :P

Answer (score 3):

Why? What does that circle add?

The new design (which is simply copied from MSO) is sharper and give more "professional" look to things in my opinion.

Comment: It's my understanding that the circle adds ... a circle.